# Razer Chroma POST Request hangs Python Script indefinitely

Tags: python, post, peripherals

I've been trying to use the Razer Chroma REST API to alter the lighting on my peripherals, but I've been stopped at the first hurdle.

According to the [Documentation](https://assets.razerzone.com/dev_portal/REST/html/index.html?_ga=2.125130184.353485604.1653189370-620268880.1637887335), to initialise a connection, you need to send a POST request to `http://localhost:54235/razer/chromasdk`, with a json payload containing the application data, but when I do this, my Python script just hangs indefinitely. No errors, no responses, it just stops at that point. The code I've been using is as below:

```
import requests
data = {
"title": "Razer Chroma SDK RESTful Test Application",
"description": "This is a REST interface test application",
"author": {
    "name": "Chroma Developer",
    "contact": "www.razerzone.com"
},
"device_supported": [
    "keyboard",
    "mouse",
    "headset",
    "mousepad",
    "keypad",
    "chromalink"],
"category": "application"
}
url = "http://localhost:54235/razer/chromasdk"
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
print(r.status_code)
```

The POST request should return a payload containing a session ID and a URI to use, or otherwise a failure response, as stated [here](https://assets.razerzone.com/dev_portal/REST/html/md__r_e_s_t_external_01_8init.html).
I've confirmed the target URL exists on my PC, as running the following code:

```
url = "http://localhost:54235/razer/chromasdk"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)"
```

returns `{"core":"3.26.00","device":"3.26.00","version":"3.26.00"}`, as expected.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!